# Printing something, leaving larger space

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Is it possible to use something like `\myphantom[xyz]{abcdef}` to print "xyz" with some alignment, but leaving space as if it were "abcdef"?

A code like:

```
\[mn xyz \myphantom[printed]{abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi} 123 456\]
\[mn xyz abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi 123 456\]
```

To print something like this:

```
mn printed                       123 456
mn abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi 123 456
```

Or:

```
mn                       printed 123 456
mn abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi 123 456
```

Or:

```
mn              printed          123 456
mn abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi 123 456
```

thank you

Comment: Is this for use in math mode or for flowing text or ... ? Some idea of the usage might help. By the way, this seems the kind of task a table-like environment would be just right for. But it's not clear from the question what the use-case is ...

Answer (score 2):

Let us make three definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\phantomwidth}
\def\myphantom#1#2{\settowidth{\phantomwidth}{{#2}}\makebox[\phantomwidth]{{#1}}}
\def\myphantoml#1#2{\settowidth{\phantomwidth}{{#2}}\makebox[\phantomwidth][l]{{#1}}}
\def\myphantomr#1#2{\settowidth{\phantomwidth}{{#2}}\makebox[\phantomwidth][r]{{#1}}}



mn xyz \myphantom{printed}{abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi} 123 456

mn  xyz abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi 123 456

mn xyz \myphantoml{printed}{abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi} 123 456

mn  xyz abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi 123 456

mn xyz \myphantomr{printed}{abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi} 123 456

mn  xyz abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi 123 456

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, using `tabular` may be more natural choice.

Answer (score 1):

I have introduced both a text mode `\myphantom` and math mode `\mathphantom` version of the command.  The math mode auto-detects the current math style and adjust the size accordingly.  The versions carry an optional placement parameter ([l], [c], or [r]).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\global\newlength\thewidth
\newcommand\findwidth[1]{\setbox0\hbox{#1}\setlength\thewidth{\wd0}}

\newcommand\myphantom[3][c]{\findwidth{#3}\makebox[\thewidth][#1]{#2}}

\newcommand\mathphantom[3][c]{\ThisStyle{%
\findwidth{$\SavedStyle#3$}\makebox[\thewidth][#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}
}}

\parindent 0in

\begin{document}

Text Mode:

mn xyz \myphantom{printed}{abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi} 123 456

mn xyz \myphantom[l]{printed}{abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi} 123 456

mn xyz \myphantom[r]{printed}{abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi} 123 456

mn xyz                     abcdefghi abcdefghi abcdefghi  123 456

Math Mode (it auto-determines math display style)

\[ 
y^{3/2} = \mathphantom{x^3}{\sum_i(A x^2 + B x + C)} + D/x
\]

\[
y^{3/2} =                  {\sum_i(A x^2 + B x + C)} + D/x
\]


\(
y^{3/2} = \mathphantom{x^3}{\sum_i(A x^2 + B x + C)} + D/x
\)

\(
y^{3/2} =                  {\sum_i(A x^2 + B x + C)} + D/x
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s. `scalerel` version 1.5 required.